# Avoid hanging sessions and table locks Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I often get hanging sessions (locking tables) in Oracle.

Without DBA privileges, are there ways to delete these sessions or unlock tables?

Is there something I can do to avoid the problem altogether?
(Some timeout settings in SQL*PLUS for example).

This is mostly SQL launched from bash-scripts.

Comment: Nopes killing sessions will require ALTER SYSTEM privilege. To check the locked objects you should be able to query v$locked_object.

Comment: Unlocking basically means to clear out the session locking the object. So killing the session will automatically clear out the locks for that session

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your DBA to delegate powers to you but there is no way to tackle these issues out of the box if you're not a DBA. Although if they are bash scripts you can kill -9 them, assuming you can figure out which PIDs need zapping.

Of course, hanging sessions are usually the result of poor system design or bad programming practice. So if you get them often you ought to look at fixing your application.

It's not possible to offer concrete advice without knowing anything about your application and what exactly causes these hangs but here are some suggestions. At the architectural level possible solutions would be cleverer job management such as scheduling or queues. Better programming practice could include pessimistic locking (`select ... for update`) and transaction management.